# I want to check if a user likes a specific "fanpage"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a landing page for a client and I want to make a "log in to check if you won" kind  of page.

For those that didn't win I want to make a "check" against the graph api if the like our clients fanpage, and if so output a special deal in html. If they don't like the page I would like to add a like our page button and the text with it to ask people to like it to gain the deal for them selves.

The login is in place but need a little help to add the rest because I can't find the "excact" need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the current context of the user, you can use the following:

```
GET /me/likes HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Grab whatever pages the user likes and see if the returned data has an ID of your page.

If you aren't in the context of the user , or want to check more explicitly, use the following API:

```
GET /{user-id}/likes/{page-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

See documentation on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/likes

Comment: Fairly new to OG and tried to search my way into a more specific way of doing this.

I understand that it requiers extra privileges to the app for "user likes" ... But could need some more extended info